# Use multiple authentication mechanisms in Azure

Tags: authentication, azure

I am new to windows azure development.
I am developing an application for hosting online tests.
This application needs to have multiple authentication options like Windows live ID, Facebook etc.
It also needs to have default form based authentication fed by the database in back end (simple User name and Password match).

Based on the authentication mechanism different permissions will be available to the user.

Can anyone please suggest how i should proceed on this?

Thanks

Comment: From your question, it seems you have not done any research whatsoever regarding your problem. A simple web search would have given answers to your question.

Comment: Sorry but as i said i am new to azure. I did some research on google but the most of the results returned were how to have multiple openId authentications like 'Google','Live Id', 'Facebook'.

None of them was how to have forms authentication and above authentications simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need forms authentication, or do you just need an application specific store where people can use a credential specific to your app?

I'd suggest researching Windows Azure Active Directory and Windows Azure Access Control Services together.  You may create either an AD tenant for your application store and use it as an Identity Provider for ACS or you could host your own Secure Token Service and Identity Provider which uses your backend database as the user store also registered with ACS.  This means that all of your authentication goes through the same process and allows for you to have your own user store, plus the social Identity Provider capability.

The key here is that you want try to avoid having forms authentication AND Social, but rather a mechanism where multiple Identity Providers can be used, including one of your own.

As Gaurav stated there are a ton of resources out there for this:

- [Understand the difference between WAAD and ACS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/06/22/azure-active-directory-is-the-future-of-acs.aspx).
- [Provisioning an Azure AD Tenant as a Identity Provider in ACS](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/03/provisioning-a-windows-azure-active-directory-tenant-as-an-identity-provider-in-an-acs-namespacenow-point-click/)
- [Windows Azure Identity](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/fundamentals/identity/)

There are also many blogs and MSDN documents talking about how to set these up.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with the default "ASP.net MVC4 Web Application" template in Visual Studio you get a web application mini-sample with an AccountController that supports local and 'social' accounts out of the box. See documentation [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc). It is based on [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/) (a fantastic lib with terrible documentation) and a Microsoft implementation of an special MembershipProvider which lives in WebMatrix.WebData.

Regarding the Azure Access Control Service 2.0: I have no idea what the status of this service is but it looks to me as if MS itself tries to discourage developers form using this service since it was to deeply hidden somewhere under Windows Azure Active Directory in the documentation.

Comment: They have stated that over time the functionality of ACS will be pulled under Windows Azure Active Directory, but for now they are separate.  AD is what MS will say is the first choice. If you need social, ACS is the way to go. http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/06/22/azure-active-directory-is-the-future-of-acs.aspx

Comment: @MikeWo: I just do not see any benefits of using ACS instead of DotNetOpenAuth. You have to install additional Identity Foundation components and you tightly couple your app to a prorpietary authentication proxy service. If you stick to DotNetOpenAuth you can easily support Google, MS, FB, Twitter etc while easily moving away from Azure to AWS for example.

Comment: Sorry, I should have worded my response differently. I was responding to the second paragraph of your answer as it mentioned the status of ACS. I didn't means ACS was superior to DotNetOpenAuth, but rather in the context of ACS vs WAAD if you need social between the two of those, ACS is what you'd use. Comparisons between ACS and DotNetOpenAuth should be made by the OP and decisions made for their scenario.